# validation form input ajax before submit

Tags: javascript, ajax, validation

I have tried to make the data input form but when an empty input form can still be saved when in press save and how when the input is empty then it will not be save.

this is my form code: https://jsfiddle.net/bubyj5xj/

```
$(".btn_save_news_item").button().click(function() {
    var form = $("#form_news_item");
    var json = ConvertFormToJSON(form);
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    url: BASE_URL + "setting/news",
    data: JSON.stringify(json),
    success: function(response) {
      console.log(response);
      resetForm();
      reloadGrid();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it will not be save"? Are you getting a specific error message? Is there no error message but the data does not get saved? Is the data being saved in a malformed format?

Comment: if input empty I want can not be saved, but in my problem an empty input form can still be saved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var form = $("#form_news_item");  
if(form=="")
{
    alert("Please fill field");
}
else
{
   $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   contentType: "application/json",
   url: BASE_URL + "setting/news",
   data: JSON.stringify(json),
   success: function(response) {
   console.log(response);
   resetForm();
   reloadGrid();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
form_text_arr = {'text': jQuery("form[name='put_ad_form']").serializeArray()};
```

after you need check each value:

```
 var reg=new RegExp(/^[A-Za-z0-9+*-]{1,10}$/);
if(reg.test(text.val)){
    .......
}
```

or

```
if(text.val == ''){
  alert('please input text');
}
```